# Sublime Text snippet to insert PSR-0 namespace

Tags: php, regex, namespaces, code-snippets, sublimetext

I'm trying to make a Sublime Text-snippet that inserts a PHP boilerplate class, in the lines of:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Subnamespace;

class TestClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //code...
    }
}
```

When using [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) standards(or similar), both the namespace and classname can be obtained from the path of the file. The file in the example above would be placed in `/Users/Projects/Whatever/src/Namespace/Subnamespace/TestClass.php`.

This is what I have so far:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<?php
namespace ${1:Namespace};

class ${TM_FILENAME/(.*)[.](.*)/$1/g}
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        ${0://code...}
    }
}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>phpclass</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

I've already figured out how to get the classname - but getting the namespace has proven to be much more difficult. I'm far from an expert in regexes - and this one requires:

1. Getting everything after `src/`
2. ...and before the last `/`
3. Flipping all the remaining slashes to backslashes.

`/Users/Projects/Whatever/src/Namespace/Subnamespace/TestClass.php` becomes `Namespace\Subnamespace`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707155/regex-for-sublimetext-snippet) is the most relevant thread I've found on the subject, but it is way over my head, and I couldn't even get it working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Not what you are asking but you may use a plugin to add the namespace automatically (see: https://github.com/gl3n/sublime-php-namespace) and a simple snippet for the rest of it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a namespace substitution that works at more than 2 levels in ST-3:

`namespace ${1:${TM_FILEPATH/(?:.*src\/)|(\/)?([^\/]+)(?=\/)|(?:\/[^\/]+\.php$)/(?1:\\$^N:$^N)/g}};`

file: `/path/to/project/src/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/class.php`

output: `namespace sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4;`

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to get it working, but it is sadly limited to a specified number of namespace-levels. Since my current project always has 2 levels (`Project\Namespace`) it works well for now. But it is not the optimal solution.

Here is the regex:

```
(?:^.*src\/|\G)(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(?:.*php|\G)
```

1. Non capturing selection of everything up to `src/`
2. Select everything to next `/`. ("Namespace")
3. Do step 2 again. ("Subnamespace")
4. Non capturing selection of the filename

Then I do a replace with `$1\\$2`, which puts the captures from step 2 and 3 with a backslash between.

The full snippet-ready version is:

```
${TM_FILEPATH/(?:^.*src\/|\G)(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(?:.*php|\G)/$1\\$2/g}
```

This will output `Namespace\Subnamespace`.

It works for now, but I would very much like to see a version that works for any number of namespace levels.